# In R, how to generate document term-doucment matrix-like data frame from a list of vectors of different size?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

Given a list of vectors of different sizes like this:

```
> input <- list(tom=c("a","b","c"),mary=c("a","c"), jack=c("a","d"))
> input
$tom
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$mary
[1] "a" "c"

$jack
[1] "a" "d"
```

I am trying to generate a data frame with each item in a vector as a indicator variable like this:

```
   name a b c d
1  tom 1 1 1 0
2 mary 1 0 1 0
3 jack 1 0 0 1
```

In other words, this is sort of like generating document-term matrix from a list
I tried looking at `tm` package of R, but it doesn't seem to support converting a list into this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
> elements <- unique(do.call(c, input))
> output <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(input, function(x) ifelse(elements %in% x, 1, 0))))
> colnames(output) <- elements
> output$name <- rownames(output)
> rownames(output) <- NULL
> output
  a b c d name
1 1 1 1 0  tom
2 1 0 1 0 mary
3 1 0 0 1 jack
```

Comment: @Alby does this suffice or were you looking for something different?